# bootstrap footer spacing issue

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that i'm working on that is Wordpress built with bootstrap. everything is working perfectly except for the footer which seems to have a space below it that will not go away. I have looked in all of the CSS and even checked to make sure it wasn't wrapped by any containers. Can someone help me out?

`http://192.185.183.130/~cedarlak/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `body` has a `padding-bottom: 51px` set. DOM/CSS inspectors like Firebug or Chrome dev tools are very useful and can help you find the cause of these issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. I noticed there is two body tags and I was looking at the very top one rather than the one that was way down the css page. Thank you very much your solution worked perfectly. Sometimes it helps to have another set of eyes on issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your body tag has extra padding at bottom. Overwrite with this

```
body{

    padding-bottom: 0px !important;

}
```

Comment: Don't override with `!important` unless absolutely necessary, that's not a standard bootstrap style so OP must have added it somewhere.